# No guarda el correo seleccionado accountManager

Tags: java, android, android-studio

Como puedo hacer para que el accountAuthenticator me guarde el email que yo le indico con el que quiero logearme en la app?

Este en mi authenticator y service:

```
public class AccountAuthenticatorService extends Service {

private static final String LOG_TAG = AccountAuthenticatorService.class.getSimpleName();
private static AccountAuthenticatorImpl sAccountAuthenticator = null;

public AccountAuthenticatorService() {
    super();
}

@Override
public IBinder onBind(Intent intent) {
    IBinder ret = null;
    if (intent.getAction().equals(android.accounts.AccountManager.ACTION_AUTHENTICATOR_INTENT)) {
        ret = getAuthenticator().getIBinder();
    }
    return ret;
}

public AbstractAccountAuthenticator getAuthenticator() {
    if (AccountAuthenticatorService.sAccountAuthenticator == null) {
        AccountAuthenticatorService.sAccountAuthenticator = new AccountAuthenticatorImpl(this);
    }
    return AccountAuthenticatorService.sAccountAuthenticator;
}

private static class AccountAuthenticatorImpl extends AbstractAccountAuthenticator {
    private Context mContext;

    public AccountAuthenticatorImpl(Context context) {
        super(context);
        mContext = context;
    }

    @Override
    public Bundle editProperties(AccountAuthenticatorResponse response, String accountType) {
        return null;
    }

    // When adding a new account from the cell phone, this window opens
    @Override
    public Bundle addAccount(AccountAuthenticatorResponse response, String accountType, String authTokenType, String[] requiredFeatures, Bundle options) throws NetworkErrorException {
        Intent add = new Intent(mContext, AccountManagerSimpleActivity.class);
        add.putExtra(AccountManager.KEY_ACCOUNT_AUTHENTICATOR_RESPONSE, response);
        Bundle reply = new Bundle();
        reply.putParcelable(AccountManager.KEY_INTENT, add);
        return reply;
    }

    @Override
    public Bundle confirmCredentials(AccountAuthenticatorResponse response, Account account, Bundle options) throws NetworkErrorException {
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    public Bundle getAuthToken(AccountAuthenticatorResponse response, Account account, String authTokenType, Bundle options) throws NetworkErrorException {
                    AccountManager am = AccountManager.get(mContext);
        String user = account.name;
        String pass = am.getPassword(account);
        String token = "sample-no-token";

        Bundle result = new Bundle();
        result.putString(AccountManager.KEY_ACCOUNT_NAME, user);
        result.putString(AccountManager.KEY_ACCOUNT_TYPE, "com.google");
        result.putString(AccountManager.KEY_AUTHTOKEN, token);
        return result;
    }

    @Override
    public String getAuthTokenLabel(String authTokenType) {
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    public Bundle updateCredentials(AccountAuthenticatorResponse response, Account account, String authTokenType, Bundle options) throws NetworkErrorException {
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    public Bundle hasFeatures(AccountAuthenticatorResponse response, Account account, String[] features) throws NetworkErrorException {
        return null;
    }

}
}
```

Si quiero registrarme me abre la ventana indicada en el addAcount.
**La clase main de registro:**

```
  // Button to execute the login from gmail account
    registration.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            String email = "com.google";
            try{
                Intent googlePicker = AccountManager.newChooseAccountIntent(null, null,
                        new String[]{email}, true, null, null, null, null);
                startActivityForResult(googlePicker, PICK_ACCOUNT_REQUEST);
            } catch (ActivityNotFoundException ex) {
                Toast.makeText(AccountManagerSimpleActivity.this, "Error de sincronización en las cuentas: " + ex.getMessage(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG);
            }
        }
    });

    cancel.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            finish();
        }
    });

}

// Function that complements the registry by gmail
@SuppressLint("WrongConstant")
@Override
protected void onActivityResult(final int requestCode, final int resultCode, final Intent data) {
    if (requestCode == PICK_ACCOUNT_REQUEST && resultCode == RESULT_OK) {
        String useremail = data.getStringExtra(AccountManager.KEY_ACCOUNT_NAME);
        Toast.makeText(this,"Cuenta sincronizada con éxito",3000).show();
    }else{
        Toast.makeText(this,"No hay cuentas sincronizadas",3000).show();

    }
}
```

Esta ventana me devuelven los correos añadidos al móvil, pero si selecciono uno de los que tengo, no me lo guarda como una cuenta conocida para que al iniciar la app se inicie automáticamente con ese correo.

**Añadido métodos en la main.**

En el onCreate:
mAccounts = mAccountManager.getAccounts();

```
    // Returns all registered accounts in the phone and executes the selected account
private void showAccountListDialog() {
    List<String> list = new ArrayList<String>();
    for (Account account : mAccounts) {
        list.add(account.name);
    }
    ArrayAdapter<String> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, list);
    AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);
    builder.setAdapter(adapter, new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
            mAccountManager.getAuthToken(mAccounts[which], "jp.example", null, mActivity, mCallback, null);
        }
    });
    builder.show();
}
```

El método asincrono para abrir la ventana al abrir la app:

```
    // Connection with the php server asynchronous
public void connSRV_async(String users, String passw) {
    try {
            listener = new XMLRPCCallback() {
                @Override
                public void onResponse(long id, Object result) {
                    // Handling the servers response
                    if(iConexion==id) {
                        code = String.valueOf(result);
                        //aproved_loguser();
                        mCallback = new AccountManagerCallback<Bundle>() {
                            @Override
                            public void run(AccountManagerFuture<Bundle> future) {
                                aproved_loguser();
                            }
                        };
                    }else{
                        Log.e("ID","Se han producido varios errores");
                    }
                }
```

He conseguido que me deje crear una cuenta y añadirla, pero no se porque al arrancar la app no inicia automáticamente...

Comment: Que versión de Android usas?

Comment: La versión 3.1.2

Comment: He realizado una modificación a ver si así es más claro